# Wrapping a frozen TensorFlow pb in a tf.keras Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use a frozen, pretrained, DeepLabv3 model in a larger tf.keras training pipeline, but have been having trouble figuring out how to use it as a tf.keras Model. I am trying to use tf.keras as I feel there would be a slowdown using a feed_dict (the only way I know of to use a frozen graph) in the middle of multiple forward passes. The deeplab model referenced in the code below is built in regular keras (as opposed to tf.contrib.keras)

```
from keras import backend as K

# Create, compile and train model...

frozen_graph = freeze_session(K.get_session(),
                        output_names=[out.op.name for out in deeplab.outputs])
tf.train.write_graph(frozen_graph, "./", "my_model.pb", as_text=False)
graph = load_graph("my_model.pb")

# We can verify that we can access the list of operations in the graph
for op in graph.get_operations():
    print(op.name)
    # prefix/Placeholder/inputs_placeholder
    # ...
    # prefix/Accuracy/predictions

# We access the input and output nodes 
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prefix/input_1:0")
y = graph.get_tensor_by_name("prefix/bilinear_upsampling_2/ResizeBilinear:0")

# We launch a Session
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    print(graph)
    model2 = models.Model(inputs=x,outputs=y)
    model2.summary()
```

and i get an error

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `tf.layers.Input`. Received: Tensor("prefix/input_1:0", shape=(?, 512, 512, 3), dtype=float32) (missing previous layer metadata).
```

I feel like I've seen others replace the input tensor with an Input Layer to trick tf.keras into building the graph, but after a few hours I am feeling stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can recreate the model object from its `config`. See the `from_config` method here https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/.

The config is stored and loaded back by the `save_model/load_model` [functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model). I am not familiar with `freeze_session`.